# How to set custom headers for html document in Playwright

Tags: node.js, playwright

In Playwright, I want to set custom headers for an html document for special identify use.

`browserContext.setExtraHTTPHeaders` and `page.setExtraHTTPHeaders` set headers for all requests in a page, but I just want to add for the html document only.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can add custom header to any request:

```js
test('Add header', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.route('https://playwright.dev', route => {
        const headers = route.request().headers();
        // Add the header:
        headers.extraHeader = 'header value'
        route.continue({ headers });
    });
    await page.goto('https://playwright.dev')
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use page.route and set the pattern match page url.